# Output of this program?

Tags: c, increment, undefined-behavior

How does the following code work?

```
main()
{
    int x = 20, y = 33;
    x=y++ + x++;
    y=++y + ++x;
    printf("%d%d", x, y);
}
```

What is the value of x and y? How the post increment takes place?

Comment: This type of question is answered thousand times

Answer (score 0):

It is compiler dependent . It has side effects .